# Link step table data with dictionary data from context/container

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have a step with table

```
Given some step with table
  |key  |value  |
  |key_1|value_1|
  |key_2|value_2|
  |key_2|value_3|
```

And a json file

```
{
  "json_key_1": "value_1"
  "json_key_2": "value_2"
  "json_key_3": "value_3"
}
```

Is there a way to:
- link table with json data like to specify via keys as variables or similar
- display got key values into report

For example:

```
Given some step with table
  |key  |value        |
  |key_1|${json_key_1}|
  |key_2|${json_key_2}|
  |key_2|${json_key_3}|
```

In this case should be next:
- Data will be gotten from json data or other dictionary by specified key in value column
- Used in step definition. 
- value will be presented in test results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: How will the value be presented in the test results?